# I want to feed power to two outlets from one outlet. Is there a problem with code doing that?

Tags: wiring

So I have an outlet in a kitchen that feeds in succession to an outlet outside. I want to run that power from that breaker to a bathroom I'm building. It's much easier for me to access that outlet in the kitchen. So I was wondering if I can keep the outlet running to outside and also attach another Romex off the kitchen outlet that is brought over to the bathroom without problems or breaking code. Never seen it done so probably not legal somehow but thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 4):

### The problem is the bathroom, not the branching

The issue you have isn't the "branch" in the circuit (T-taps, if you will, are a normal part of building wiring), it's that you can't have bathroom receptacles on the same branch circuit as things that aren't in a bathroom, or non-receptacles that aren't in the same bathroom as all the bathroom receptacles served by the circuit:

> **(3) Bathroom Branch Circuits.** In addition to the number of
> branch circuits required by other parts of this section, at least
> one 120-volt, 20-ampere branch circuit shall be provided to
> supply the bathroom(s) receptacle outlet(s). Such circuits shall
> have no other outlets.

> *Exception: Where the 20-ampere circuit supplies a single bathroom,
> outlets for other equipment within the same bathroom shall be permitted
> to be supplied in accordance with 210.23(A)(1) and (A)(2).*

So, if you don't have a receptacle-only bathroom branch circuit you can tap, you'll have to pull a new homerun of 12/2 from the panel to meet Code.  Note also that you can't tap most kitchen receptacle circuits to feed lighting, either, as the kitchen small appliance branch circuits aren't allowed to serve non-kitchen-receptacle loads, period.

Answer (score 1):

> **210.11 Branch Circuits Required.**
> **(C) Dwelling Units**.
> **(1) Small Appliance Branch Circuits**. In addition to the
> number of branch circuits required by other parts of this
> section, two or more 20-ampere small-appliance branch circuits
> shall be provided for [kitchen receptacles only].
> **(3) Bathroom Branch Circuits**. In addition to the number
> of branch circuits required by other parts of this section, at
> least one 120-volt, 20-ampere branch circuit shall be provided
> to supply a bathroom receptacle outlet(s). **Such circuits
> shall have no other outlets.**

So, bathroom receptacles can't be on the same circuit with any other room's receptacles.

Your kitchen-outdoor situation may be "grandfathered" as legal when it was initially installed... However you can't make a grandfathered situation *worse* by adding additional outlets to it.

Comment: How interesting. Figured having a gfci outlet in the bathroom would be enough. A bigger picture of this situation is the kitchen outlet in question was for a refrigerator which I moved to a different wall and ran a dedicated breaker to that outlet. So it presently isn't even connected to a breaker. The other outlets in the kitchen are dedicated to one breaker. I'm assuming the outside outlet was ran off the old refrigerator outlet as it worked when I moved into this house but no longer had power. I can only assume it's because it was fed off the old refrigerator outlet.